# AngularJS - Set focus to next textbox after first textbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-watch

Hi I am currently working of datetime picker input in my two textboxes.

[image]

What I want to do is, after the user choose date in the first textbox, a datetime picker of second textbox will pop up. The user does not need to click the second box.

This is my code.

html

```
<md-input-container>
    <input time="true" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="date" placeholder="Start Date" ng-model="date">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <input time="true" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="date" placeholder="End Date" ng-model="date">
</md-input-container>
```

javascript

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .controller('DemoCtrl_{{boundField.name}}', function ($scope, mdcDateTimeDialog) {
      $scope.date = new Date('{{boundField.value()}}');
      $scope.dateTime = new Date();
      $scope.minDate = moment().subtract(1, 'month');
      $scope.maxDate = moment().add(1, 'month');

      $scope.displayDialog = function () {
        mdcDateTimeDialog.show({
          maxDate: $scope.maxDate,
          time: false
        })
          .then(function (date) {
            $scope.selectedDateTime = date;
            console.log('New Date / Time selected:', date);
          });
      };

    })
  ;
})();
```

[image]

I am new to angularjs expecially the javascript part. Your help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: if you want it to tab, you can do `tabindex="1" and tabindex="2"` to both inputs

Comment: you may try daterangepicker for this functionality.

Comment: You can bind the `input` event on the first text box in a directive then just move the focus on the second text box.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what I need. @Jai, May you please help me out with my codes in binding the input event and also how to move the focus on the second textbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use tab indexes like below

**Update**

I have updated the id and ng-model variables. You were using the same names for both start and end date whihc is not correct.

**HTML code is as below**

```
<md-input-container>
    <input time="true" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="startdate" placeholder="Start Date" ng-model="startdate" tabindex="1">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
    <input time="true" date="true" mdc-datetime-picker type="text" id="enddate" placeholder="End Date" ng-model="enddate" tabindex="2">
</md-input-container>
```

**The watcher code is as below**

```
$scope.$watch('startdate', function (oldval,newval) {
        if(oldval!=newval)
        {
            var enddate = document.getElementById('enddate');
            enddate.focus();
        }
    });
```

**Just add this watcher code in your controller**

Once you select the date in first textbox, it will check if the value is same as previous. If not then it will set the focus on the enddate.

Comment: i guess you missed the actual question.

Comment: @Jai: looks he wanted the cursor to point the second text box. tabindex is good solution for this issue. Please let me know if i missed something.

Comment: What i understood is: when user selects a date in the first text box then right after that event.... datepicker for second input should be opened. without any other event.

Comment: @Jai That is exactly what i want to do. Thanks

Comment: @Jai. Thanks.. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much.!! This is a great help!! I wish i could return the favor to both of you.

Comment: @JamesReid: That's great. Thanks